# I want to hide header view and detailed cell from the tableview, how could I achieve this?

Tags: ios, swift

Hide/Show header view and detailed cell from the tableview, how could achieve this? Advance thanks to any answers

I have some option based on that wanna hide and show the deatils contained cell and header view from the uitabeview cell. Please any one can help me. Also how can access tableview cell from outside dalegate methods to fix out this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [ask].

Comment: What have you tried? please show us.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using tableView **viewForHeaderInSection section** or **heightForHeaderInSection section**

the method you can easily put condition when to show or when to hide hope it'll help you!

Comment: Thank you so much @RAHUL NIMJE, I achieved this by simply reloading tableview based on certain condition.